# Function() does not exist in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I am facing a problem requesting the following login URLs. It is giving me an error. Could anyone help me solve this issue?

> ReflectionException Function () does not exist" error.

Comment: Are you upgrading the code from older laravel or is it freshly written in laravel 8?

Comment: It was freshly written in laravel 8.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the routes file
Route::get('/', [YourControllerFile::class,'Function class']);
it's becaause you did'nt assigne the fucntion's class
you did like this:
Route::get('/', [YourControllerFile::class]);